# Delete multiple indices in one Elasticsearch HTTP request (cURL)

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-indices

I was using this `curl` command line to clean my indices:

```
curl -XDELETE http://example.com/my_index-*
```

But, now, I want to delete `my_index-.*[.][0-3][0-9]`:

- to delete only `my_index-YYYY.MM.dd`
- to keep `my_index-YYYY.MM.dd-*`

---

The relevant Elasticsearch documentation I have found:

- [Delete index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/indices-delete-index.html) does say nothing on regex.
- [Multiple indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/multi-index.html) says:

  > It also support wildcards, for example: `test*` or `*test` or `te*t` or `*test*`, and the ability to "add" (`+`) and "remove" (`-`), for example: `+test*,-test3`.
- [Date math support in index names](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/date-math-index-names.html) says:

  > Almost all APIs that have an `index` parameter, support date math in the `index` parameter value.
  >   [...]
  >   `date_format` is the optional format in which the computed date should be rendered. Defaults to `YYYY.MM.dd`.

---

My Questions:

- **Is it possible to send a `DELETE` request method to Elasticsearch HTTP server to delete indices only formatted `my_index-YYYY.MM.dd`?**
- **Or the inverse, to delete all `my_index-*` but keeping `my_index-*-*`?**

---

For example, regex can sometimes be provided within the `POST` data:

```
curl -XPOST http://example.com/my_index-2017.07.14/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "suggest": {
        "song-suggest" : {
            "regex" : "n[ever|i]r",
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "suggest"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 46):

### Short answer

Delete all indices `my_index-*` except indices `my_index-*-*`

```
curl -X DELETE http://es.example.com/my_index-*,-my_index-*-*
```

### No regex

Elasticsearch 5.x does not accept regex or filename patterns `?[a-z]` to select multiple indices.

However, the [multiple indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/multi-index.html) documentation allows `+` and `-` to include and exclude indices.

Script to prevent accidental deletion of indices `my_index-*-*`:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
pattern="${1:-*}"
curl -X DELETE https://es.example.com/my_index-"$pattern",-my_index-*-*?pretty
```

### Explanation

- The parameter `index` can contain a comma separated list of index patterns, for example `my_index_1,my_index_2,my_index_3`.
- Index pattern is based on wildcards, for example `my_index*`.
- To include and exclude indices, use `+` and `-` as index prefix, for example `my_index_*,-my_index_2017*,+my_index_2017-01*,-my_index_2017-01-31`.
- Do not need to use `+` on first index

### Described example

This `DELETE` request deletes all indices `my_index_*` before `my_index_2017-01-31`

```
index_list='my_index_*,-my_index_2017*,+my_index_2017-01*,-my_index_2017-01-31'
curl -X DELETE http://es.example.com/"$index_list"
```

- Delete all `my_index_*`
- Except `my_index_2017*`
- Delete `my_index_2017-01*`
- Except `my_index_2017-01-31`